# How can I determine the most efficient query execution plan from the following choices

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having one doubt,
I performed the following test, and obtained the below results

1. qry-1 --> cost=2, consistent_gets=5
2. qry-2 --> cost=3, consistent_gets=5
3. qry-3 --> cost=3, consistent_gets=3

## how can I identify which query is the most efficient one and how?

```
Oracle - 12.2.0.1
query rewrite -> disabled
dynamic sampling -> disabled
create table test_01 as select * from all_object;
create index ix_test_01 on test_01(object_id);
-- gathered stats
-- then ...
```

## qry-1

```
select * from test_01 where object_id=(select max(object_id) from test_01);

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 753718840

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |            |     1 |   134 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TEST_01    |     1 |   134 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IX_TEST_01 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    SORT AGGREGATE                   |            |     1 |     5 |            |          |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN (MIN/MAX)       | IX_TEST_01 |     1 |     5 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("OBJECT_ID"= (SELECT MAX("OBJECT_ID") FROM "TEST_01" "TEST_01"))


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          5  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
       2504  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        608  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

## qry-2

```
select /*+ first_rows(1) */ * from test_01 order by object_id desc fetch first 1 rows only;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 905071378

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |            |     1 |   507 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |            |     1 |   507 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY       |            |     1 |   134 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_01    | 64489 |  8438K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING| IX_TEST_01 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=1)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY INTERNAL_FUNCTION("TEST_01"."OBJECT_ID")
              DESC )<=1)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          5  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
       2504  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        608  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

## qry-3

```
SQL> select * from
  2  (
  3  select /*+ first_rows(1) */ * from test_01 order by object_id desc
  4  )
  5  where rownum<=1;


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1996576387

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |            |     1 |   481 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                |            |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                        |            |     1 |   481 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_01    | 64489 |  8438K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING| IX_TEST_01 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM<=1)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          3  consistent gets 
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
       2504  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        608  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

-- Which one from the above query should I choose and why?

Comment: Are these being run with actual data volumes and distributions?  If so, it seems odd to spend time optimizing this query since all three approaches are doing a minimal amount of I/O and no sorts.  Unless this is a query inside of a very tight loop in which case you'd want to take a step back and find a way to do set-based processing rather than row-by-row processing.

Comment: As you are on 12.2, you can use the `fetch first` syntax (equivalent to query 3). By the way, I doubt that hint is doing anything.

Comment: -- Thanks for the comment @WilliamRobertson
I have tried the ```fetch first``` in qry-2

Answer (score 0):

qry-1 looks is most efficient, because result of subquery is single id.

qry-2 and qry-3 build subset (VIEW) of sorted values and then top row is selected form the sorted set

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I also think so.. only  the count of cosistent gets is surprising me

Answer (score 0):

Query 3 is 14% faster than query 1 or query 2.  The best way to determine which query is better is with an experiment.

Although I agree with Justin Cave that these performance comparisons are probably meaningless.  Converting to set-based processing is usually better than optimizing tiny queries in loops.

But it's useful to have different methods for comparing performance.  Looking at the execution plans and using `AUTOTRACE` is a great start, but directly measuring the queries' runtime is the best way to measure performance.

### Setup

I started with your original code

```
create table test_01 as select * from all_objects;
create index ix_test_01 on test_01(object_id);
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TEST_01');
end;
/
```

The tests are PL/SQL blocks.  PL/SQL is the perfect tool for this because it runs on the server, and won't be affected by client or network time.  I used my IDE to measure the times, but you could also use DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME to measure it directly on the server for even more accurate results.

Most Oracle databases are on shared servers, so it's important that the results aren't affected by other workloads.  To help avoid interference, I'll typically run the tests cases in order, then repeat, throw out the high and the low, and take an average.

### PL/SQL Tests

```
--Query 1 (2.74 seconds): 2.718, 2.758, 2.706, 2.754, 2.749.
declare
    type v_test_tab is table of test_01%rowtype;
    v_tests v_test_tab;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
        select * bulk collect into v_tests from test_01 where object_id=(select max(object_id) from test_01);
    end loop;
end;
/

--Query 2 (2.73 seconds): 2.690, 2.741, 2.757, 2.728, 2.721
declare
    type v_test_tab is table of test_01%rowtype;
    v_tests v_test_tab;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
        select /*+ first_rows(1) */ * bulk collect into v_tests from test_01 order by object_id desc fetch first 1 rows only;
    end loop;
end;
/

--Query 3 (2.35 seconds): 2.378, 2.322, 2.306, 2.357, 2.359
declare
    type v_test_tab is table of test_01%rowtype;
    v_tests v_test_tab;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 100000 loop
        select * bulk collect into v_tests from
        (
            select /*+ first_rows(1) */ * from test_01 order by object_id desc
        )
        where rownum<=1;
    end loop;
end;
/
```